# How to add sites to the Safari Power Saver exclusion list?

Tags: macos, safari, power-management, adobe-flash, plugins

In Safari, a feature I really like is that flash plugins are automatically blocked by default and you have to click in order to start the flash plugin (see, e.g., http://mac-fusion.com/manage-the-safari-power-saver-feature/). I found, however, that it prevents Google Play's "play music" buttons from working, so I had to temporarily disable the feature (uncheck the "Stop plug-ins to save power" box) and restart Safari in order to listen to music on Google Play.

There is some sort of exclusion list. I currently have 3 sites listed, but I do not know how they got there. How do I add a site, e.g. `play.google.com`, to this list?

I don't see a UI to do this, but perhaps there is a way of editing a plist to insert a new entry?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5514058) will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Thecafremo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/21487/thecafremo)'s [tip](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5514058), the responsible file is `~/Library/Safari/PlugInOrigins.plist`.  I found an AppleScript published by GitHub user [crmne (Carmine Paolino)](https://github.com/crmne), `SafariPowerSaverWhitelister.scpt`, that is supposed to add entries (https://gist.github.com/crmne/5855a901a0a9a6ef30a5).  You might try it, but it did not work for me in Safari 7.0.3.

Instead, after clicking on a "play music" button, I opened up Web Inspector and ran the following JavaScript on the console:

```
window.embedElem = document.querySelector("embed");
embedElem.style.position = "fixed";
embedElem.style.width = "100px";
embedElem.style.height = "100px";
embedElem.style.top = "500px";
```

There was a 100x100 black square hovering on the left of the page toward the bottom.  After clicking it, Safari added an entry to the exclusions list for `play.google.com`.